# MySQL Join Query. Only show entries that do not exist

Tags: mysql

We have two tables Accounts and Jobs. Our business requires that every Account has one job each year. In example below 'ABC Ltd' has 3 jobs, 'DEF Ltd' has 2 jobs, and 'XYZ Ltd' nas no jobs.

```
Table Accounts
id | account
1  | ABC Ltd  
2  | DEF Ltd
3  | XYZ Ltd 

Table Jobs
acc_id | job_name | year
1      | Job KLM  | 2018
1      | Job 2Z   | 2019
1      | Job M5   | 2020   
2      | Job AB   | 2018
2      | Job C    | 2019

* tables are joined on id = acc_id
```

Now in 2020 we want to make sure that all missing jobs are scheduled. What query I need to run which would give me the list of the 'missing' jobs for 2020?

E.g. result I am looking for is:

```
DEF Ltd 
XYZ Ltd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL terms, what you're trying to do is:

- join Accounts to Jobs, including accounts that have no matching jobs (a "left join" - there are also "right join" which would give you jobs with no matching accounts, "outer join" which would give you both, and "inner join" which would give you neither)

`SELECT a.account FROM Accounts a LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs j ON a.id = j.acc_id AND j.year = 2020`

- filter out the ones that have jobs

`... WHERE j.job_name IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT account FROM `Accounts` WHERE id not in (select acc_id from Jobs where year='2020')
```

Comment: If worked, accept the answer and make an upvote. 
Thank you